# Subsets Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

### Textbook Question:

[image]

### Textbook Solution:

[image]

### Formula or Mathematical Proof ?

I have seen different ways of calculating the number of subsets, such as $n \choose k$ and $2^k$, but I don't know what is the right way to do it for this question. Is there a formula, or mathematical proof that I don't know about ?

Comment: My textbook have not provided enough clarification for this example problem, any clarification would be helpful for me to understand what approach I need to take

Comment: Subsets of $B$ include some elements of $A$ and they either include $x$ or they don't. Thus they are exactly the subsets of $A$ and subsets of $A$ "plus" $x$. I think you'll be able to solve the other question(s) using similar logic.

Comment: Keep in mind that $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of subsets of size $k$ in a set with $n$ elements, while $2^k$ is the number of subsets of a set with $k$ elements.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to clarify one piece of terminology here. The power set of a set $A$, $\mathscr P(A)$, is the set of all subset of $A$, including $A$ itself and the null set. So, $|\mathscr P(A)|=n$ tells us that $A$ has $n$ subsets. The set $B$ is just the set $A$, but with one new element $x$. This means we should be able to make twice as many subsets as before because we can make all the same subsets of $A$ ($n$ subsets) plus those same subsets, but now including the new element $x$ (again, $n$ subsets). This same logic can be applied to parts b and c.

Comment: Hmm,makes sense. Thanks for clarification my friend. :)